# Kafka connect - > S3 Parquet file byteArrey

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, parquet, apache-kafka-connect

I'm Trying to use Kafka-connect for consumes Kafka's message and write them to s3 parquet file.
so i wrote a simple producer which produce messages with byte[]

```
Properties propertiesAWS = new Properties();
    propertiesAWS.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "myKafka:9092");
    propertiesAWS.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class.getName());
    propertiesAWS.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getName());


    KafkaProducer<Long, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<Long, byte[]>(propertiesAWS);
    Random rng = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Headers headers = new RecordHeaders();
            headers.add(new RecordHeader("header1", "header1".getBytes()));
            headers.add(new RecordHeader("header2", "header2".getBytes()));
            ProducerRecord<Long, byte[]> recordOut = new ProducerRecord<Long, byte[]>
                    ("s3.test.topic", 1, rng.nextLong(), new byte[]{1, 2, 3}, headers);
            producer.send(recordOut);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }
```

and my kafka connect configurations is:

```
{
"name": "test_2_s3",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "aws.access.key.id": "XXXXXXX",
    "aws.secret.access.key": "XXXXXXXX",
    "s3.region": "eu-central-1",
    "flush.size": "5",
    "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "10000",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "s3.test.topic",
    "parquet.codec": "gzip",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "s3.bucket.name": "test-phase1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.LongConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
    "store.kafka.headers": "true"
}
```

and this is the error  i got:

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Avro schema must be a record.
at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroSchemaConverter.convert(AvroSchemaConverter.java:124)**

where is my mistake ?
do i need to use Avro even that i just want to write the byteArr + some Kafka Headers?
how to configure which kafka header to write to parquet ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ParquetFormat` writer requires Avro data with a schema of `type: record`, yes.

You could use a schema like this, though.

```
{
    "namespace": "com.stackoverflow.example",
    "name": "ByteWrapper",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "data",
        "type": "bytes"
    }]
}
```

> configure which kafka header to write to parquet

None. Kafka headers are just bytes, and have no designated serialization format.

To use ParquetFormat, you'll need to change your producer to use KafkaAvroSerializer from Confluent and also use their AvroConverter in Connect to deserialize that data prior to writing Parquet.

---

If you want to write only bytes to S3, use [`ByteArrayFormat`](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/master/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/format/bytearray/ByteArrayFormat.java) instead

Comment: Thanks,
why it's required to produce the message with avro?
can i do the conversation within my connector ?
my current topic is not in avro format so in order to make it work do i need to duplicate the topic with avro messages ?

Comment: Look at the error? `Avro schema must be a record`, so you can't use any unstructured format. Json schema or Protobuf might work, but haven't tested. Otherwise, yes, you'll have to duplicate some data. But still, in your case, Parquet is a columnar format, for analytics, not long term, raw storage of bytes

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
it's working and i have parquet files in s3.
but the files doesn't contains the kafka's header.
any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure. Last time I used S3 sink, it only supported writing record values. Kafka record keys and values would have separate schemas, so unless the full record ends up in one Parquet file, it's not clear to me if headers would be written alongside the key or the value